# How to expand variables inside read?

Tags: bash, read

In a remote CentOS with Bash 5.0.17(1) where I am the only user via SSH I have executed `read web_application_root` with:

```
$HOME/www
```

or with:

```
${HOME}/www
```

or with:

```
"${HOME}"/www
```

or with:

```
"${HOME}/www"
```

Aiming to get an output with an expanded (environment) variable such as `MY_USER_HOME_DIRECTORY/www`.

While `ls -la $HOME/www` works fine, `ls -la $web_application_root` fails with all examples; an error example is:

```
ls: cannot access '$HOME/www': No such file or directory
```

I understand that `read` treats all the above `$HOME` variants as a string (due to the single quote marks in the error) and hence doesn't expand it.

How to expand variables inside read?

Comment: What shell are you using? Note that you are reading _code_ from the user. As such, it would need to undergo an extra step of evaluation before the actual value (the pathname) is had. Such an evaluation could be done with `eval`, but if you're using the  `zsh` shell, then there are better (safer) ways of doing that.

Comment: `eval` usage on user input is probably no good idea, because it could lead to the user executing commands you have not intended.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, I have updated to describe the shell.

Comment: And if the user enters `$(reboot)` or `${HOME+$(reboot)}`, should `ls -la $web_application_root` reboot?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't have enough knowledge to fully understand your comment but I can tell you that the session I work with is pretty straightforward; it's an SSH session to pretty much run a script and `exit`.

Comment: @Jaleks I am the only user in the entire environment (it's a private hosting environment I SSH to). Please consider to write an answer with `eval` based on that fact (then, I assume there is no worry from other users running commands on the same system).

Comment: The OP comments (SE cookie lost): “After reading Stéphane Chazelas's answer or what I could mentally read (let along get) from it, I say that I insist to working with `read` because I sorely need its interactivity but I can't use the `envsubst` utility because my website hosting plan doesn't include it (neither the new one I prepare to move to) so I seek a shell-only solution which would allow people lacking `envsubst` (or any other non-shell-builtin utility) to achieve the original goal in the question.
All parts about `envsubst` are better to be hidden in some dropdown window, I think.”

Comment: (The above was submitted as an edit but is more appropriate as a comment.)

Comment: @Kusalananda: What is the safer way to do this in `zsh`?

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham `${(e)web_application_root}` would expand the variable `web_application_root` to `$HOME/www` and then apply a second re-evaluation to the result, expanding any further variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables are not expanded when passed to `read`. If you want to expand the `$VAR`s or `${VAR}`s where `VAR` denotes the name of an existing environment variable (limited to those whose name starts with an ASCII letter or underscore and followed by ASCII alnums or underscores) and leave all the other word expansions (`$non_exported_shell_variable`, `$1`, `$#`, `${HOME+x}`, `$((1 + 1))`, `$(cmd)`...) untouched, you could use `envsubst` (from GNU `gettext`):

```
IFS= read -r web_application_root || exit
web_application_root=$(printf %s "$web_application_root" | envsubst)
ls -la -- "$web_application_root"
```

You could make it a shell function that takes a variable name as argument and does both the reading and environment variable expansion with:

```
read_one_line_and_expand_envvars() {
  IFS= read -r "$1"
  ret="$?"
  command eval "$1"'=$(printf %s "${'"$1"'}" | envsubst)' && return "$ret"
}
```

To be used for instance as:

```
printf >&2 'Please enter the root dir (${ENVVAR} expanded): '
read_one_line_and_expand_envvars web_application_root || exit
printf >&2 'The expanded version of your input is "%s"\n' "$web_application_root"
```

To limit that substitution to a limited set of environment variables, you'd pass the list as a `$VAR1$VAR2...` literal argument to `envsubst`:

```
web_application_root=$(
  printf %s "$web_application_root" |
    envsubst '$HOME$MYENVVAR'
)
```

(here tells `envsubst` to only substitute `$HOME`, `${HOME}`, `$MYENVVAR` and `${MYENVVAR}` in its input, leaving all other `$VAR`s untouched).

If you want to allow all forms of word expansions¹ (but note that then that makes it a command injection vulnerability), you could do:

```
web_application_root=$(eval "cat << __EOF__
$web_application_root
__EOF__")
```

Or again, as a function that takes the variable name as argument:

```
read_one_line_and_perform_shell_word_expansions() {
  IFS= read -r "$1"
  ret=$?
  command eval '
    case "${'"$1"'}" in
      (EOF) ;;
      (*)
        '"$1"'=$(command eval "cat << EOF
${'"$1"'}
EOF")
    esac' && return "$ret"
}
```

```
printf >&2 'Please enter the root dir ($var/$((...))/$(cmd) allowed): '
read_one_line_and_perform_shell_word_expansions web_application_root || exit
printf >&2 'The expanded version of your input is "%s"\n' "$web_application_root"
```

The same function with detailed inline documentation:

```
read_one_line_and_perform_shell_word_expansions() {
  # first argument of our function is the variable name or REPLY
  # if not specified.
  varname=${1-REPLY}

  # read one line from stdin with read's unwanted default post-processing
  # (which is otherwise dependant on the current value of $IFS) disabled.
  IFS= read -r "$varname"

  # record read's exit status. If it's non zero, a full line could not be
  # read. We may still want to perform the expansions in whatever much
  # was read, and pass that exit status to the caller so they decide what
  # to do with it.
  ret=$?

  # We prefix the "eval" special builtin with "command" to make it lose
  # its "special" status (namely here, exit the script about failure,
  # something bash only does when in standard mode).
  command eval '
    # the approach we take to expand word expansions would be defeated
    # if the user entered "EOF" which is the delimiter we chose for our
    # here-document, so we need to handle it as a special case:
    case "${'"$varname"'}" in
      (EOF) ;;
      (*)
        # the idea here is to have the shell evaluate the
        # myvar=$(command eval "cat << EOF
        # ${myvar}
        # EOF")
        #
        # shell code when $1 is myvar, so that the
        #
        # cat << EOF
        # contents of $myvar with $(cmd), $ENV and all
        # EOF
        #
        # shell code be evaluated, and those $(cmd), $ENV expansions
        # performed in the process
        '"$varname"'=$(command eval "cat << EOF
${'"$varname"'}
EOF")
    esac' &&
      # unless eval itself failed, return read's exit status to the caller:
      return "$ret"
}
```

But your problems sounds more like an XY problem. Getting input via `read` is cumbersome and impractical. It's much better to get input via arguments, and then you can leave it to the caller's shell to do the expansions as *they* intend it.

Instead of

```
#! /bin/sh -
IFS= read -r var
ls -l -- "$var"
```

(and remember that [calling `read` without `IFS=` and without `-r` is almost never what you want](/q/209123)).

Make it:

```
#! /bin/sh -
var=${1?}
ls -l -- "$var"
```

And then the caller can do `your-script ~/dir` or `your-script "$HOME/dir"` or `your-script '$$$weird***/dir'` or even `your-script $'/dir\nwith\nnewline\ncharacters'` as they see fit.

---

<sup>¹ *word expansion* in this context refers to *parameter expansion*, *arithmetic expansion* and *command substitution*. That doesn't include *filename generation* (aka *globbing* or *pathname expansion*), *tilde expansion* nor *brace expansion* (itself not a standard `sh` feature). Using a here-document here makes sure `'` and `"`s are left untouched, but note that there still is backslash processing.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! About the last two code examples --- in that scenario I must use `read`.

Comment: @variableexpander It's such an unusual thing to want to do, so it would be interesting to see why you think you need to use `read` to read something that needs further shell evaluation.

Comment: @Kusalananda I just want to give any one who uses the script I write (on its own environment) the option to define a certain web application root; for example, not all users would have it under ${HOME} as in my case.

Comment: @variableexpander Stéphane's last piece of code seems rather on point then. Take the pathname on the command line. This is commonly done by most other utilities that require the user to supply some form of pathname.

Comment: @Kusalananda did you mean to `#! /bin/sh -
var=${1?}
ls -l -- "$var"`? I don't know how this could help me.

Comment: @Stéphane I believe my problem is not an XY problem because I want to prompt myself for the variable value and not strictly predetermine it; the reason is because I might run the same script on different systems where the web application root might be on various paths. Furthermore, I also want to use variables which are based on existing variables such as `domain_dir=$web_application_root/$domain` and `read` is the only way I know to define such variables via prompting.

Comment: @variableexpander, I think the point they're trying to make is that most utilities _don't_ prompt the user for values. Instead, they take the values from command line arguments, or environment variables, and just complain if a required value is not set. That is, you'd call them as `whatever -d /my/webapp/root`, or put something like `export WEBAPPROOT=/somedir` in your shell startup files beforehand. Not using `read` does not mean predetermining the value, and relying on `read` might not be a good idea wrt. user expectations either.

Comment: @ilkkachu all the ways you mentioned aren't ways to prompt the user or I miss something (sorry if I do); in my special case *I do indeed* need to prompt the user for such details.

Comment: `you can leave it to the caller's shell to do the expansions as *they* intend it` the script I try to develop is only for Bash (different version could interpret differently, I know).

Comment: @variableexpander, see the example invocations of `your-script` I gave where the user can use whatever expansion or quoting feature of their shell they want to pass the directory name as the first argument to the script.

Comment: Okay, I copied the function `read_one_line_and_perform_shell_word_expansions()` to clipboard, pasted it on console and executed it. I then copied to clipboard only `read_one_line_and_perform_shell_word_expansions web_application_root || exit` and finally I could use `read` to hold a variable expansion as a variable value.

Comment: I admit I don't totally understand the code of the function and might likely ask a separate question about it because I really want to understand it.

Comment: @variableexpander, the edit for a commented version.